# pandas plot: how to plot some columns of a dataframe with the same color but different style and some cols with different color and different style?

Tags: python, pandas

Assume a DataFrame `df` with three Series, `S1`, `S2` and `S3`.

I want to plot

- `S1` with blue color and continuous-line,
- `S2` with blue color and dashed-line,
- `S3` with green color and continuous-line.

I could call the `Series.plot()` three times, but what if I want to use `DataFrame.plot()`?
In other words, I want to use the method `df[[S1,S2,S3]].plot()` but I have no ideas what parameters to pass to the method `plot()`.
So far, I only found that I can pass a `matplotlib` `colormap` but that does not seem to solve my problem.

Comment: Thanks. Now it matches. But it way less clear IMHO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `style` option:

```py
linestyles = ['b', 'b--', 'g']
df.plot(style=linestyles)
```

[image]